# Libgdx not regging taps when tapping fast

Tags: libgdx

I'm making a game where a guy needs to run faster when you tap faster, but

Gdx.input.isTouched()

Stops working when I tap on the screen very fast, then it just keeps on being false.

Any ideas?

Comment: What phone?   Have you checked if it is a phone specific issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

Libgdx can have its input handled in two main ways.

One way is polling, as you have implemented it. This method is [considered unreliable](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Polling), as it only checks whether something is pressed or not at any time.

The other method is by using an [input processor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling). Creating an input processor as described in this link allows you to handle rapid presses as soon as they occur.

Implementing an input processor should resolve problems with rapid tapping.

Comment: Nope, makes no difference. I'm adding to a variable directly from public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) now and it stills stalls when I tap too fast.

Comment: Would you mind posting some of your code? It would probably help in troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to insert my code here without it looks like crap, so here is : [link]http://wankfeed.com/misc/code.txt[/link]

The counter stops counting completly if I tap VERY fast on the screen (Samsung 10.1"TAB).. and the faster I tap the more interruptions it makes in counting up.. at slow paces it counts as it should.